# Getting error no suitable image url loader found for IOS App

Tags: react-native

[when ios app run first time login this error come and when i close it he goes but every time when i login the app Looks again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i02pC.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Seems you are using The image url which is generated from Android device as its starting from `content://`. You need to check the url to correctly. load in the iOS.